# Auto Changing Text Case

Tags: permalinks, pages, navigation, theme-twenty-eleven, customization

So I'm using all static pages and I specify that in my WP settings. When I specify what the 'Front Page' should be it turns my link in to Title Case instead of all Capital Letters like I would prefer. I have set in all caps in the title of my page so I'm not sure why it is converting it or how to stop it from converting it.

I'm using the default 'twenty eleven 1.2' theme not sure if it has something to do with that or not. Can somebody help me please? Here's a link to what I'm talking about.

http://www.trileafweb.com/omni/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that you're using the default, fallback navigation menu instead of a defined, custom navigation menu. (The "Home" link you're seeing is the default home link output by `wp_page_menu()`.)

Go to **Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus**, to define and apply a custom navigation menu. By applying your static front page explicitly, the custom nav menu item will use Post Title, rather than the default "Home" text being used by the default "Home" link output by `wp_page_menu()`.

Alternately, you could apply some CSS:

```
#access li {
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: >Menus = MindBlown - Had no idea about this which is pretty convenient! Thanks man!